# How to not show panel after create ExtJs

Tags: extjs, extjs6-classic

I want to create side panel with slide animation but when I'm create it panel flashing.
My code:

```
Ext.define('Admin.view.test.SidePanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    xtype: 'widget.side-panel',
    reference: 'SidePanel',
    controller: 'test',
    width: '80%',
    height: '100%',
    floating: true, // make this panel an absolutely-positioned 
    floating component
    title: 'Test',
    renderTo: 'myContainer',
    defaultAlign: 'tr-tr',
    html: 'Test Panel',
    region: 'east',
    headerPosition: 'top'
});
```

And create this panel:

```
var panel = Ext.create('Admin.view.test.SidePanel', {}).getEl().slideIn('r', {
    duration: 3000
});
```

Please help me define my problem or show best way how to do this.
My fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ls6

Comment: You question is not clear. Please explain more exactly what you need.

Comment: @NarendraJadhav I want create drawer panel. Witch will be eave right to left

Comment: @a.yushko please share your code with JSFiddle.

Comment: @AvinashT. See my fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ls6. It dose not work correctly because panel flashing